Username in chat room info title bar may be partially, or completely, hard to see depending on the window width, chat room and browser
In most cases, the username is shown as white text on a black background in the chat room info title bar, so if the window width is wide enough, it's easy to read. For example, with a maximized window for SO Close Vote Reviewers, there's

However, if the window width is narrower than the defined page width, the black background only extends to that initial width, so scrolling to the right then causes the right black border to move to the left (even if the page is refreshed). This may leave the username partially or fully without that background, making it hard to see. Here's where my username is only partially visible:

If the window is narrow enough, then scrolling to the right has the entire name being almost invisible:

Note that I got this same behavior, but only for most chat room info pages, with FireFox (Version 115.14.0esr (64-bit)) on Windows 7, plus Google Chrome (Version 127.0.6533.120 (Official Build) (64-bit)) and Microsoft Edge (Version 127.0.2651.105 (Official build) (64-bit)) on Windows 10. However, with just Microsoft Edge on several Math site related chat room info pages, e.g., 2024 Mathematics Stack Exchange Moderator Election Chat, Math Mods' Office and CURED, the username is displayed instead with a dark (apparently a shade of blue or purple) color font. Thus, the opposite issue occurs there. With a maximized window for CURED, we have

while after scrolling to the right in a small width window, the username is then quite easy to read

I primarily use Edge with the SE sites, and I'm fairly certain the username text color used to also be white on the Math chat room info pages. However, if so, since I don't usually pay much attention to it, I'm unsure about when it changed. Nonetheless, as the color is apparently the same, and I believe it happened around the same time, this is likely related to my post of Visited chat info page buttons now have a dark background color, making them hard to read about those chat rooms' info buttons visited text color being changed, although that particular issue has now been fixed (i.e., their text color is now white again).

Update: Note that, as indicated in Username in chat now has wrong color as a visited link, the issue with the dark colored text being used for the username is actually not related to the particular browser and chat room, as I stated above. Instead, it occurs when the link has been "visited". That's why this only occurred for me originally with several chat rooms, where I've visited my user's chat profile page previously using Microsoft Edge. However, I've now confirmed that, for example, my username text also shows with a dark color in Edge with SO Close Vote Reviewers, and Google Chrome with CURED, after I clicked my username links there.

@Carrott Thanks for the update. I, and believe most other members, consider fixing the visited link issue to be more important, so I'm glad that fix, at least, should be coming this week.

The visited link issue (purple text on dark background) is now [status-completed], the small width window issue is logged but low priority so I'm marking this as [status-deferred]

@Carrott I noticed the visited link issue was fixed quite a while ago, but I appreciate you letting me know about it. Regarding the small width window issue, I agree it's fairly low priority (but I'm glad that it's logged so it's in your system). FWIW, I also think that marking this question as [status-deferred] makes sense.
