Username in chat now has wrong color as a visited link
This seems similar to this bug report: Visited chat info page buttons now have a dark background color, making them hard to read. It is now marked status-completed. Maybe fixing the issue in that thread broke the display of username.
If you go to https://chat.stackexchange.com/ or https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/, near the top, there is a link with your username - it can be used to go to your profile.
But once you visited your profile, the link becomes blue and the visibility is rather low.
A screenshot from https://chat.stackexchange.com/:

A screenshot from https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/:


Similar, not duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/402345/username-in-chat-room-info-title-bar-may-be-partially-or-completely-hard-to-se   But, the display of username didn’t report in that post.

@user1176409 FYI, based on what this question states, I checked to confirm that the dark color username text is not due to the chat room and browser, as I stated in my question that you linked to. Instead, it's just due to whether or not I've "visited" my user's profile chat page with that browser. I've added an update to the end of that question to clarify this.

There is a fix coming (should be this week) for the Visited link issue (dark username text on dark background).
